# How can I solve this python egg_info error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I get this error while installing "tsne". I am following [this](https://github.com/danielfrg/tsne) documentation for installation. Both methods throw the same error.

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-IVtJ7x/tsne/
```

**EDIT:**

Find the screenshot here.
[SCREENSHOT- CLICK ME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyu2B.png)

Comment: Is it the only line you get? What are your `/tmp` mount options?

Comment: @Marat I have just edited my question with the screenshot.

Comment: This package seems to only support python2 and you're installing it in python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it clearly says there is a syntax error in the `setup.py`. I checked the [PyPi version](https://pypi.python.org/packages/1b/45/e4e14d3f4a535fee125a52e52a537fb8b79cf60dd9cef3491bc8905d898a/tsne-0.1.5.tar.gz#md5=73aaa99c9d36b8b9dba631ae69f8a194) and it includes this debug line:

```
print '!!!!!!!!!!!!!', find_packages()
```

This line will not cause problems for Python2, but will be considered a syntax error in Python3. I assume your default python is Python3.

The github version does not have this line, so installation from github should work:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/danielfrg/tsne.git
```

If it does not, my best shot would be to use scikit-learn as the author of the package [suggessted](https://github.com/danielfrg/tsne):

> Note: Scikit-learn v0.17 includes TSNE algorithms and you should
>   probably be using them instead of this.

Comment: How can I change it to Python2? I just installed python2. Thus, my system has python2 and python3 now.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you not to change the default python, because many system programs rely on it. Instead, you can specify python version explicitly, e.g. `python2 myscript.py`. You can also use `pip2` and `pip3` to install packages